# Как изменить отдельную ячейку в таблице на странице (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно сделать чтобы пользователь на сайте мог вводить данные в БД. Создал вот такую таблицу: [image: Таблица выводит данные из БД]
С библиотекой jQuery сделал ввод данных в таблицу, вот код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()    {
    $('td').click(function(e)   {
        //ловим элемент, по которому кликнули
        var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
        //получаем название тега
        var elm_name = t.tagName.toLowerCase();
        //если это инпут - ничего не делаем
        if(elm_name == 'input') {return false;}
        var val = $(this).html();
        var code = '<input type="text" id="edit" value="'+val+'" />';
        $(this).empty().append(code);
        $('#edit').focus();
        $('#edit').blur(function()  {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().empty().html(val);
        });
    });
});

$(window).keydown(function(event){
    //ловим событие нажатия клавиши
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {   //если это Enter
        $('#edit').blur();  //снимаем фокус с поля ввода
    }
});
</script>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы вводить данные можно было только в определенные ячейки? Сейчас получается вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать, чтоб столбец "№", "Дата/Время" и первую строку невозможно было изменить, а остальные возможно. Есть ли вообще такая возможность? Думаю, что все просто, но в js не шарю.
Библиотека jQuery-3.3.1.js

Comment: <input disabled="disabled">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто - первую строку оберните в тэг `<thead>`, остальные ячейки в `<tbody>`. Ячейкам которые не нужно редактировать добавьте класс
`<td class="lock">`.
И селектор будет выглядеть так:
`$('tbody td').not('.lock').click.....`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать атрибут `contenteditable`, также можно размещать `<input>`-ы только там, где это необходимо или использовать атрибут `readonly` для `<input>` в которые запрещён ввод.

```js
$('td,th').on('input',function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
th{
  font-weight:400;
}
td,th{
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№</th>
      <th>Дата/Время</th>
      <th>ФИО</th>
      <th>Адрес</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12.12.1212</td>
      <td contenteditable>ААГ</td>
      <td contenteditable>defaultCity</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>11.11.1111</td>
      <td contenteditable>ББА</td>
      <td contenteditable>defaultCity</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Как все на самом деле просто), спасибо.